# If _StringBetween didn't find the value

Tags: autoit, winhttprequest

I have created a simple script in AutoIT that checks if a string exists or not, if it exists it will show label else it will show another label here is the script :

```
$text = $oHTTP.ResponseText
$status = $oHTTP.Status
If $status = 200 Then
    $array = _StringBetween($text, '<span class="d1">', "</span>")
    If $array[0] == "" Then
        GUICtrlSetState($v2l1, $GUI_SHOW)
    ELSE
        GUICtrlSetState($v2l2, $GUI_SHOW)
    EndIf
Else
    ConsoleWrite(@error)
EndIf
```

if it find anything then the label will appear but if it didn't find the string it gives me an error and exit:

`Subscript used on non-accessible variable.:
If $array[0] == "" Then
If $array^ ERROR`

So is there anyway i can fix this ? I mean if $array didn't find the string it make $v2l2 visible.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [IsArray](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/IsArray.htm) to test whether you received a valid array or not. This procedure is recommended whenever you call a function that returns an array.

```
If $status = 200 Then
    $array = _StringBetween($text, '<span class="d1">', "</span>")
    If IsArray($array) Then
        ; process the array
    Else
        ; handle the error
    EndIf
EndIf
```

Comment: Yours was the first explanation of this widely-reported problem that helped me. Thanks!

Comment: This is what you need to use when `IsDeclared` is not working for returned arrays. I wish they documented that on IsDeclared; it's an aggravating bug.

Answer (score 1):

Use @error which is set by _StringBetween(), this is proper AutoIt coding.

```
If $status = 200 Then
     $array = _StringBetween($text, '<span class="d1">', "</span>")
     If Not @error Then
         ; process the array
     Else
         ; Handle the error
     EndIf
EndIf
```

Comment: I have used @error but in another way :), anyway thanks, much appreciated.